# POPC Purchase Order Process

Tags: moqui

[image]We are trying to understand the purchase process in Moqui. We are using the PoP Commerce sample data.

We created a purchase order in the name of "ZiddlemanInc: Ziddleman & Sons Suppliers Inc." for item "Demo Product One-One" : 1000 quantity. We were shown a warning about payment which was ignored and order was placed.

We created an incoming shipment of "Demo Product One-One" from "ZiddlemanInc". We updated the shipment as "shipped".

We were shown a warning while creating the shipment. The screen shot of warning has been attached.

Is there any alternate option to create a shipment linked to purchase order? Further, how do we link this shipment, not linked to purchase order, to the purchase order?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general documentation for Procure to Pay (ie purchasing):

https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/apps/POPC+ERP+User+Guide/Procure+to+Pay

This document does not have step by step instructions but mentions looking up a PO and creating a shipment which should be done from the Order Detail screen.

This is similar to the fulfillment process (uses the same screens but a different flow for shipping vs receiving a Shipment) and the doc for that has more detail and you can see the documentation for that here:

https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/apps/POPC+ERP+User+Guide/Order+to+Cash/Ship+Sales+Order

Comment: We added a new supplier and created a purchase order (login: john.purchasing). We could not figure out how to create a shipment from order details screen.

Comment: We don't see "Create Shipment" button in "Purchase Order Part" section.